Is there a way in Systemerilog to know if data type is object type or other basic type?
I am trying to learn System Verilog classes. I created a parameterized class, where one of the parameters is affecting the data type of one of the fields.
    class Node  #(parameter type T = int, parameter BASIC_TYPE = 1);
        T data;

I wanted to create a copy function inside this Node class, so that data is copied. Data could be any type, so it could be a bit for example or an object of class. If data was an object, it should have copy implemented on it, so doing something like data.copy() should be expected to work;
however I am thinking about scenario where a bit is used, that would result in an error. I thought of adding a parameter to the class BASIC_TYPE, which would be used like this:
void function copy(node target);
if(BASIC_TYPE==0)
data.copy(target.data);
else
target.data = node.data;
endfunction

I wonder if there is some built-in function that could be used to check if the variable is object or have copy implemented on it, instead of relying on the passed parameter.

Nope. You could somehow figure out the type, but you can't write conditional code based on that information.

You can test the type of a variable using the type() operator
if (type(target.data)==type(int)) target.data = node.data;
But the problem if data you can't have code which directly calls the copy() method of a class if the variable is not a class, even if that code is not reachable.
There is a solution to this using what is called a policy or strategy design pattern. Basically you can create another object whose sole purpose is implementing a copy variables of the desired type. This is more involved for a beginner, but here are two references from DVCon presented paper
Design Patterns by Example for SystemVerilog Verification Environments Enabled by SystemVerilog 1800-2012
SystemVerilog Constraint Layering via Reusable Randomization Policy Classes
